# signal callback and pthread sync

Tags: c, sockets, serial-port, pthreads, signals

On my app I have a pthread running a while(1) that read a socket client and a serial callback function. My app receive messages from a serial (like /dev/ttyS0) and receive messages from socket. The problem: the app crash after receive some messages from serial, on this moment the socket is receiving nothing. But if I comment the thread creation the app work fine.

code draft:

```
// Socket Thread
static void *Socket(void *arg)
{
  // socket inicialization
  while (1)
  {
    ret = read(client, buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1);
    // do something
  }
}

// serial callback
static void SerialCallback(int id, unsigned char *buffer, int length)
{
    // do something
}

// main
int main (void)
{
  // start and configure serial callback
  cssl_start();
  Serial = cssl_open(SERIAL_PORT, SerialCallback, 0, 115200, 8, 0, 1);

  // create the pthread
  // If I comment the line below the app work fine
  pthread_create(&Thread_Socket, NULL, Socket, NULL);

  while (1)
  {
  }
}
```

Notes:

- I use the library cssl (http://sourceforge.net/projects/cssl/) to deal with serial. This library use a real time signal.
- For tests purposes I use socat to generate pseudo-terminals (like /dev/pts/XX)
- The serial callback is called each time that serial receive one or more bytes
- I am using the cutecom to send messages to serial

---

Added new tests information in 2012.07.16

First test: I replace the line of read function by a while(1); and the problem follow (so, the problem is not related with read function).

Second test: Using the full code (above example), I use two external usb/serial converter loopback connected, work rightly.

Comment: Can you provide the error/crash report?

Comment: no erros, quit silently.

Comment: The signal delivery probably interrupts your `read(2)` in the socket-reading thread. Check the value of `errno(3)`. Is it `EINTR`?

Comment: `if (ret == -1) { perror("read failed"); exit(1); }`

Comment: I do the verification of ret after read function, no error. I cannot trace where the app get out. The app exit without errors.

Comment: What exactly is happening in `SerialCallback()`?  A quick look at the `cssl` library shows that it's called in the signal context - you're limited in what you can do in that context.

Comment: Nothing special in SerialCallback. I use the functions memset and memcpy to work with the a global buffer - store the message. After, I call the ParseMessage function (just strcmp funtions). The ParseMessage is too called by socket when it receive a message, but this don't happen on same time.

Comment: Are you sure `sizeof(buffer)` works as expected? `sizeof` for a string will return count of bytes upto the first `null` terminator. Try passing hardcoded read size to eliminate possibility of memory corruption.

Comment: What is the declaration of the global variable `buffer`?

Comment: @puffadder your affirmation about sizeof is not correct.

Comment: @alk the buffer declaration not is a pointer.

Comment: @RicardoCrudo Yep it isn't. Sorry about that :( I saw buffer as a pointer in `SerialCallback()` args and thought it would be the same for `Socket()`

Comment: Please provide a working example to be able to reproduce the malfunction. The code posted so far is much to incomplete to be checked ...

Answer (score 1):

How said @Nikolai N Fetissov, the program break because EINTR signal. I looked into cssl library code and change the flags of signal, from: `sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;` to `sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO | SA_RESTART;`. Worked.

I contacted Marcin Siennicki, cssl project developer, and sent the link of this post for him.

Thanks for comments.